# Multiple parameter sets and PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am building a function which will have three distinct parameter sets, and two of those sets will overlap with the third. The options would look like this:

```powershell
A B
A C
A (D E F)
A B (D E F)
A C (D E F)
```

To make it a little more clear, here is a partially completed version the function:

```powershell
function Move-AccountOut {

    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='NoTransferHomeDrive')]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [string]$Username,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainGroups')]
        [switch]$RetainGroups,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromAllGroups')]
        [switch]$RemoveFromAllGroups,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$False)]
        [switch]$TransferHomeDrive,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$OldServer,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$NewServer
    )
}
```

The purpose of the function is to automate the process of transferring out an AD account to another location within the company. `RetainGroups` would automatically retain the users groups when set, and `RemoveFromAllGroups` would automatically remove the user from their groups. The two switches should not be able to be used together. Additionally, if `TransferHomeDrive` is set, it will call a function to schedule a transfer using an internal tool.

To put it another way, `RetainGroups` and `RemoveFromAllGroups` should be a member of all parameter sets (similar to `Username`), but should not be able to be used together.

I have tried two ways. The first:

```powershell
function Move-AccountOut {

    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='NoTransferHomeDrive')]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [string]$Username,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainGroups')]
        [switch]$RetainGroups,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromAllGroups')]
        [switch]$RemoveFromAllGroups,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$False)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainGroups')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromAllGroups')]
        [switch]$TransferHomeDrive,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainGroups')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromAllGroups')]
        [string]$OldServer,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainGroups')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromAllGroups')]
        [string]$NewServer
    )
}
```

Using this technique, retain and remove cannot be used together, but `OldServer` and `NewServer` are no longer mandatory. If I change them to:

```powershell
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainGroups', Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$OldServer,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainGroups', Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$NewServer
```

They will be mandatory, but it no longer cares whether `TransferHomeDrive` is set.

If I set it up the opposite way:

```powershell
function Move-AccountOut {

    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='NoTransferHomeDrive')]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [string]$Username,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainGroups')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive')]
        [switch]$RetainGroups,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromAllGroups')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive')]
        [switch]$RemoveFromAllGroups,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$False)]
        [switch]$TransferHomeDrive,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$OldServer,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$NewServer
    )
}
```

Then `OldServer` and `NewServer` will be mandatory, but `RetainGroups` and `RemoveFromAllGroups` can be used together. Additionally, if I use retain and remove together, then `OldServer` and `NewServer` become mandatory, but not when they are used on their own.

How do I make this work?

Comment: I am currently parsing all of this, but what really helps in using parameter sets is to use `Get-Help` on your functions to show you how PowerShell is interpreting your parameter sets. If you could do that for each of the configurations you've tried, and then edit the output into your answer, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Great question, thanks!

Answer (score 23):

Ok, I think I understand this. The possible combinations you want are:

1. `-RetainGroups`
2. `-RemoveFromAllGroups`
3. `-RetainGroups` plus `-TransferHomeDrive`
4. `-RemoveFromAllGroups` plus `-TransferHomeDrive`
5. Only `-UserName`
6. `-UserName` plus `-TransferHomeDrive`

I am assuming that `-OldServer` and `-NewServer` only apply when moving the home drive, so whenever you are moving the home drive, they are mandatory. If that is not the case, let me know.

So what you have here are *6 parameter sets*. As powerful as powershell's parameter set magic is, there isn't a good way to say "these 2 switches are mutually exclusive but should also be available in all parameter sets" so you have to multiplex it and repeat every parameter set with one or the other.

```powershell
function Move-AccountOut {
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='OnlyUser')]
Param( 
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$True, 
        ValueFromPipeline=$True, 
        ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True
    )]
    [string]
    $Username,

    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$True,
        ParameterSetName='RetainOnly'
    )]
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$True,
        ParameterSetName='RetainAndTransfer'
    )]
    [switch]
    $RetainGroups,

    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$True,
        ParameterSetName='RemoveOnly'
    )]
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$True,
        ParameterSetName='RemoveAndTransfer'
    )]
    [switch]
    $RemoveFromAllGroups,

    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$True,
        ParameterSetName='RetainAndTransfer'
    )]
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$True,
        ParameterSetName='RemoveAndTransfer'
    )]
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$True,
        ParameterSetName='TransferOnly'
    )]
    [switch]
    $TransferHomeDrive,

    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$True,
        ParameterSetName='RetainAndTransfer'
    )]
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$True,
        ParameterSetName='RemoveAndTransfer'
    )]
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$True,
        ParameterSetName='TransferOnly'
    )]
    [string]
    $OldServer,

    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$True,
        ParameterSetName='RetainAndTransfer'
    )]
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$True,
        ParameterSetName='RemoveAndTransfer'
    )]
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$True,
        ParameterSetName='TransferOnly'
    )]
    [string]
    $NewServer
)

}
```

The output of `Get-Help Move-AccountOut`:

> ```powershell
> Move-AccountOut -Username <string>  [<CommonParameters>]
>
> Move-AccountOut -Username <string> -RetainGroups -TransferHomeDrive -OldServer <string> -NewServer <string>  [<CommonParameters>]
>
> Move-AccountOut -Username <string> -RetainGroups  [<CommonParameters>]
>
> Move-AccountOut -Username <string> -RemoveFromAllGroups -TransferHomeDrive -OldServer <string> -NewServer <string>  [<CommonParameters>]
>
> Move-AccountOut -Username <string> -RemoveFromAllGroups  [<CommonParameters>]
>
> Move-AccountOut -Username <string> -TransferHomeDrive -OldServer <string> -NewServer <string>  [<CommonParameters>]
> ```

## Simplifying It

If you want to make it less daunting, you might consider consolidating the remove and retain switches into a single parameter, something like this:

```powershell
[Parameter(
    Mandatory=$false # you can leave this out
)]
[ValidateSet(
    'None',
    'Retain',
    'RemoveAll'
)]
[String]
$GroupAction = 'None'
```

This would reduce your parameter sets down to 2, and make your entire definition look like this:

```powershell
function Move-AccountOut {
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='OnlyUser')]
Param( 
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$True, 
        ValueFromPipeline=$True, 
        ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True
    )]
    [string]
    $Username,

    [ValidateSet(
        'None',
        'Retain',
        'RemoveAll'
    )]
    [String]
    $GroupAction = 'None' ,

    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$True,
        ParameterSetName='TransferOnly'
    )]
    [switch]
    $TransferHomeDrive,

    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$True,
        ParameterSetName='TransferOnly'
    )]
    [string]
    $OldServer,

    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$True,
        ParameterSetName='TransferOnly'
    )]
    [string]
    $NewServer
)

}
```

With the following `Get-Help` output:

> ```powershell
> Move-AccountOut -Username <string> [-GroupAction <string> {None | Retain | RemoveAll}]  [<CommonParameters>]
>
> Move-AccountOut -Username <string> -TransferHomeDrive -OldServer <string> -NewServer <string> [-GroupAction <string> {None | Retain | RemoveAll}]  [<CommonParameters>]
> ```

I do want to point out that although that's simpler to *define* that doesn't mean it's better. It may be that you want to optimize your parameter sets for the **caller** which can be especially important if this is a function you plan on using interactively a lot from the shell, rather than calling from other scripts (and it seems like this may be the case).

So adding some complexity in the definition to make it easier to use might be the right thing to do.

Comment: Well now don't I look silly, you wrote pretty much the same answer as me (plus more) almost 45 minutes before me. Wish I'd seen this before I submitted my answer.

Comment: Eh, it happens to all of us at some point, @TheMadTechnician. :)

Comment: This is the best explanation of PowerShell parameter sets I've seen on the web.  This answer is much better than the standard MSDN pages.

Comment: Thanks @RossPatterson !

Answer (score 8):

By adding two more Parameter Sets you can do what you want. This is needed because you have 3 sets now, plus a non-set parameter (which technically puts it in the `__AllParameterSets` set if I remember right). So that's 4 ways of doing it. You need 6 ways of doing it if I am reading your question correctly. You want all of the following options:

```psh
Move-AccountOut -Username <string>  [<CommonParameters>]
Move-AccountOut -Username <string> [-RetainGroups] [-TransferHomeDrive] [-OldServer <string>] [-NewServer <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]
Move-AccountOut -Username <string> [-RetainGroups]  [<CommonParameters>]
Move-AccountOut -Username <string> [-RemoveFromAllGroups] [-TransferHomeDrive] [-OldServer <string>] [-NewServer <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]
Move-AccountOut -Username <string> [-RemoveFromAllGroups]  [<CommonParameters>]
Move-AccountOut -Username <string> -OldServer <string> -NewServer <string> [-TransferHomeDrive]  [<CommonParameters>]
```

So we will add the `RemoveFromAllGroupsWTran` and `RetainGroupsWTran` Parameter Sets, add them both to `$TransferHomeDrive`, `$OldServer`, and `$NewServer` (removing the other related set names from them), then add each to its respective switch parameter. It ends up looking like this:

```psh
function Move-AccountOut {

    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='NoTransferHomeDrive')]
    Param( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [string]$Username,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainGroups')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainGroupsWTran')]
        [switch]$RetainGroups,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromAllGroups')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromAllGroupsWTran')]
        [switch]$RemoveFromAllGroups,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$False)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainGroupsWTran')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromAllGroupsWTran')]
        [switch]$TransferHomeDrive,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainGroupsWTran')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromAllGroupsWTran')]
        [string]$OldServer,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferHomeDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainGroupsWTran')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveFromAllGroupsWTran')]
        [string]$NewServer
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `[ValidateScript()]`, if have two `Mandatory = false` parameters in all parameter sets, and you need to use them only together, e.g.:

```
function SomeFunction {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
[Parameter (Mandatory = $true,
ParameterSetName = "A")]
[Parameter (Mandatory = $true,
ParameterSetName = "B")]
[Parameter (Mandatory = $true,
ParameterSetName = "C")]
[switch]$Param1,
[Parameter (Mandatory = $true,
ParameterSetName = "A")]
[switch]$Param2,
[Parameter (Mandatory = $true,
ParameterSetName = "B")]
[string]$Param3, 
[Parameter (Mandatory = $true,
ParameterSetName = "C")]
[string]$Param4,
[Parameter (Mandatory = $false,]
[ValidateScript({
                    if ($Param6) {
                    $True                         
                    }
                    else {
                    throw "This parameter will work only with parameter [Param6]"
                    } 
                }
)]
[string]$Param5,
[Parameter (Mandatory = $false)]
[ValidateScript({
                    if ($Param5) {
                    $True                         
                    }
                    else {
                    throw "This parameter will work only with parameter [Param5]"
                    } 
                }
)]
[string]$Param6
...
}
```