# Using contradicting parameters in Powershell

Tags: function, powershell

For my lab i'm trying to do some automation while trying to get better at Powershell in the mean time. Currently I'm use the two functions pasted below:

```
#Set a new hostname for a local virtual machine.
function New-VmHostname ($VmHostname, $NewComputerName, $credential) {
    Invoke-Command -VMName $VmHostname {
        Rename-Computer -NewName $using:NewComputerName -Force} -Credential $credential
}

#Set a new hostname for a remote machine.
function New-RemoteHostname ($RemoteHostname, $NewComputerName, $credential) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $RemoteHostname {
        Rename-Computer -NewName $using:NewComputerName -Force} -Credential $credential   
}
```

Now I'm trying to write a function to be able to incorporate both functions above. Something like this:

```
#Set a new hostname for a lab machine
function New-Hostname {
    # Parameter help description
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,
            Mandatory=$True,
            ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [string]$VmName,
        [Parameter(Position=1,
            Mandatory=$True,
            ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [string]$NewComputerName,
        [Parameter(Position=2,
            Mandatory=$True,
            ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [ValidateSet("Remote","VM")]
        [string]$RemoteSessionType
    )

    # Do stuff

}
```

What I want is for the function to have a parameter, `$RemoteSessionType`, to decide if the cmdlet downline uses the `-VMName` or uses the `-ComputerName` parameter. I can't seem to figure out how though.

Comment: Relevant questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202916/powershell-multiple-parameter-sets, https://superuser.com/questions/929743/using-advanced-parameter-sets-in-a-function-with-multiple-unique-switches

Comment: This would be easier if you used parametersets. One for Remote and one for VM.