# Trouble with multiple parameter sets

Tags: powershell, parameters, parameter-sets

I need to get three parameters for a function that I am creating. Parameter one must be in all parameter sets. The other two parameters has multiple permutations.

I tried playing around with the parameter sets and I've searched for other threads, but none of them seem to be discussing this scenario.

My question is how do I create the parameter sets so that there are only the following possibilities.

```
Test-ParametersNow -ParamZ <string> -ParamA <string> -Param1 <string>
Test-ParametersNow -ParamZ <string> -ParamA <string> -Param2 <string>
Test-ParametersNow -ParamZ <string> -ParamA <string> -Param3
Test-ParametersNow -ParamZ <string> -ParamA <string> -Param4
Test-ParametersNow -ParamZ <string> -ParamA <string> -Param5
Test-ParametersNow -ParamZ <string> -ParamB -Param1 <string>
Test-ParametersNow -ParamZ <string> -ParamB -Param2 <string>
Test-ParametersNow -ParamZ <string> -ParamB -Param3
Test-ParametersNow -ParamZ <string> -ParamB -Param4
Test-ParametersNow -ParamZ <string> -ParamB -Param5
Test-ParametersNow -ParamZ <string> -ParamC <string> -Param1 <string>
Test-ParametersNow -ParamZ <string> -ParamC <string> -Param2 <string>
Test-ParametersNow -ParamZ <string> -ParamC <string> -Param3
Test-ParametersNow -ParamZ <string> -ParamC <string> -Param4
Test-ParametersNow -ParamZ <string> -ParamC <string> -Param5
```

Here is my function.

```
function Test-ParametersNow{
[CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position = 0)][string]$ParamZ,


        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Param1", Mandatory=$false)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Param2", Mandatory=$false)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Param3", Mandatory=$false)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Param4", Mandatory=$false)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Param5", Mandatory=$false)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamA", Mandatory=$true,Position = 1)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string]$ParamA,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Param1", Mandatory=$false)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Param2", Mandatory=$false)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Param3", Mandatory=$false)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Param4", Mandatory=$false)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Param5", Mandatory=$false)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamB", Mandatory=$true,Position = 1)][switch]$ParamB,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Param1", Mandatory=$false)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Param2", Mandatory=$false)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Param3", Mandatory=$false)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Param4", Mandatory=$false)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Param5", Mandatory=$false)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamC", Mandatory=$true,Position = 1)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string]$ParamC,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamA", Mandatory=$false)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamB", Mandatory=$false)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamC", Mandatory=$false)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Param1", Mandatory=$true,Position = 2)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string]$Param1,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamA", Mandatory=$true)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamB", Mandatory=$true)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamC", Mandatory=$true)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Param2", Mandatory=$true,Position = 2)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string]$Param2,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamA", Mandatory=$true)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamB", Mandatory=$true)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamC", Mandatory=$true)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Param3", Mandatory=$true,Position = 2)][switch]$Param3,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamA", Mandatory=$true)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamB", Mandatory=$true)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamC", Mandatory=$true)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Param4", Mandatory=$true,Position = 2)][switch]$Param4,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamA", Mandatory=$true)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamB", Mandatory=$true)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamC", Mandatory=$true)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Param5", Mandatory=$true,Position = 2)][switch]$Param5
    )
}

#Show-Command Test-ParametersNow
Get-Help Test-ParametersNow
```

These are the results that I get from Get-Help Test-ParametersNow

```
NAME
    Test-ParametersNow

SYNTAX
    Test-ParametersNow [-ParamZ ] <string> [-ParamA] <string> -Param2 <string> -Param3 -Param4 -Param5 [-Param1 <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Test-ParametersNow [-ParamZ ] <string> [-Param5] [-ParamA <string>] [-ParamB] [-ParamC <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Test-ParametersNow [-ParamZ ] <string> [-Param4] [-ParamA <string>] [-ParamB] [-ParamC <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Test-ParametersNow [-ParamZ ] <string> [-Param3] [-ParamA <string>] [-ParamB] [-ParamC <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Test-ParametersNow [-ParamZ ] <string> [-Param2] <string> [-ParamA <string>] [-ParamB] [-ParamC <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Test-ParametersNow [-ParamZ ] <string> [-Param1] <string> [-ParamA <string>] [-ParamB] [-ParamC <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Test-ParametersNow [-ParamZ ] <string> [-ParamB] -Param2 <string> -Param3 -Param4 -Param5 [-Param1 <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Test-ParametersNow [-ParamZ ] <string> [-ParamC] <string> -Param2 <string> -Param3 -Param4 -Param5 [-Param1 <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]


ALIASES
    None


REMARKS
    None
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You seem to have forgotten to ask a question! Please, at the very least, describe what the _expected behavior_ you're looking for is, and how the current behavior deviates from that expectation!

Comment: I have to agree with Mathias on this one. You likely have an interesting and answerable question here, but we need clarity on your _expected output_, how do you _want_ it to work? In the meantime, see if [this answer helps you at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30202916/3905079).

Comment: My question is how do I set up the parameter sets so that it will only accept the three parameters.<br/>For example: Test-ParametersNow -ReuiredParam string -ParamA string -Param1 string.<br/>If I use ParamA I should not have an option anymore for ParamB or ParamC, only Param1-Param5.

Comment: @briantist I saw that one already, but I don't think it answers my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined 8 different parameter sets (A,B,C,1,2,3,4,5), but since each of A, B, or C each has 5 options, it seems like you want 15: A1 thru A5, B1 thru B5, C1 thru C5. Each parameter (except Z), belongs to several of these sets as required. Like this:

```
function Test-ParametersNow{
[CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position = 0)][string]$ParamZ,


        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamA1", Mandatory=$true,Position = 1)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamA2", Mandatory=$true,Position = 1)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamA3", Mandatory=$true,Position = 1)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamA4", Mandatory=$true,Position = 1)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamA5", Mandatory=$true,Position = 1)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string]$ParamA,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamB1", Mandatory=$true,Position = 1)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamB2", Mandatory=$true,Position = 1)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamB3", Mandatory=$true,Position = 1)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamB4", Mandatory=$true,Position = 1)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamB5", Mandatory=$true,Position = 1)]
        [switch]$ParamB,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamC1", Mandatory=$true,Position = 1)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamC2", Mandatory=$true,Position = 1)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamC3", Mandatory=$true,Position = 1)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamC4", Mandatory=$true,Position = 1)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamC5", Mandatory=$true,Position = 1)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string]$ParamC,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamA1", Mandatory=$true,Position = 2)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamB1", Mandatory=$true,Position = 2)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamC1", Mandatory=$true,Position = 2)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string]$Param1,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamA2", Mandatory=$true,Position = 2)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamB2", Mandatory=$true,Position = 2)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamC2", Mandatory=$true,Position = 2)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string]$Param2,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamA3", Mandatory=$true,Position = 2)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamB3", Mandatory=$true,Position = 2)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamC3", Mandatory=$true,Position = 2)]
        [switch]$Param3,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamA4", Mandatory=$true,Position = 2)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamB4", Mandatory=$true,Position = 2)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamC4", Mandatory=$true,Position = 2)]
        [switch]$Param4,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamA5", Mandatory=$true,Position = 2)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamB5", Mandatory=$true,Position = 2)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ParamC5", Mandatory=$true,Position = 2)]
        [switch]$Param5
    )
}
```